# Is there an online Markdown editor with auto-complete feature?

Tags: text-editor, markdown

*Or alternatively an installable one for linux...*

I mean a feature that propose on the fly alternatives while typing for the most common words, for instance typing "veh" would propose "vehicle".

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: apart from auto-complete, what other features do you need? Have you checked with [similar questions already answered](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=markdown+editor+answers%3A1)?

Comment: Do you need it to autocomplete only Markdown syntax? Could you give an example of what you type and what it should propose? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Just write generic contents and be able to autocomplete the most common words. Something like `Ctrl-p` in Vim.

Comment: Do you mean the most common words in English, for instance typing "veh" would propose "vehicle"?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes

Comment: Now edit your question to add all of this information, comments will get deleted.

Comment: My coworker recommends prose.io

Answer (score 1):

I use [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext) editor for Markdown text in Ubuntu, which I installed from Ubuntu Software. ReText is written in Python language and works on Linux and other POSIX-compatible platforms. The latest stable version of ReText can be downloaded from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ReText). You can also use the `pip install ReText` command to install it from there.

Type in your markdown text and then press the <kbd>[image: IMG:] Preview</kbd> button to see what the formatted markdown text looks like. Alternatively you can enable live preview by default in ReText by selecting *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> check *Use live preview by default*.

ReText supports tabs, live text preview and syntax highlighting. Spell checking can be enabled with *Edit* -> *Spell check* -> *Enable*. Supported export formats: HTML, ODT, PDF.

All known third-party extensions for ReText are listed in [Python-Markdown wiki](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I use Yosoro in windows platform.
it doesn't support autocopmlete but it has two pane editor with wysiwyg support